# How do I run a Liquibase changeLogFile from my classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, classpath, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot application that is configured to run Liquibase.  I'm trying to set up a separate project that will be used as the database management project.  It will store all of `liquibase.properties` files for different databases.

My database management project depends on my main app because it needs to load the chaneglogFile.  However, my database management project cannot find the changelogFile on the classpath.

Here is the folder structure of the main project.  The changelog is in `src/main/resources` so maven automatically adds it to the classpath

[image]

Here is the configuration in the `liquibase.properties`

```
changeLogFile=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

As well as the maven plugin configuration

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.my-group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And the resulting error

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.2:status (default-cli) on project my-app-db: Error setting up or running Liquibase: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml does not exist
```

Comment: the `classpath:` prefix is a Spring specific feature, you probably need `/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`, see also https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html

Comment: @RobertScholte I tried that but didn't have any success.

Answer (score 0):

what about trying

`changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`

does that work for you?